# Mouse scrolling not working on child grid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have One WPf window. In which I have multiple grids, textbox and labels. 
I have enabled mouse scrolling in parent grid. The mouse scrolling is working fine in that.
but when the mouse cursor come over the child grids the scrolling stop working. where as at other place on the page its working fine.Please suggest

The structure of the page is somewhat like this.

```
<grid>

  <grid></grid>
   <textbox>
   </textbox>
   <label></label>
</grid>
```

Comment: I think this is a question eventhandling. What if you'd watch mouse movement and if it is "inside" any of the other grid rather than parent you'd give focus to the control (?) and apply scrolling functionality

Answer (score 0):

Set Background="Transparent" for child grid.